# Flutter problem: How to validate when data is not matching?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is my code

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:cwc/constants/card_top.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/activities.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_page_changer.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/components/search_components.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  const Event({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}

class _EventState extends State<Event> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 210,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff80CAD7),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/bg_dummy.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 12, 0, 0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child:
                            Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 125, 18, 0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                height: 60,
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  controller: eventController,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    hintText: 
                       'Search for Events',
                     
                    suffixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.search_outlined,
                      color: Color(0xFF444444),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 190),
              child: Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Activities()),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Color(0xff80CAD7),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        },
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        child: Image.asset('assets/home_icon.png'),
        elevation: 5.0,
        highlightElevation: 10,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: BottomNavBarEvent()),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Acitivity.dart page.

Here my "eventsUpcomingListData" variable, In this I had three data,when I searched "te" keyword then it should be show test1 and test2 data but in this case test1 and test2 and with this "No data" showing where my "no data" test should be show when data not matching then.

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../../skeleton.dart';

class Activities extends StatelessWidget {
  const Activities({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Upcoming Events",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize24, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isEventLoading
            ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SliderSkeleton(),
                      SliderSkeleton(),
                      SliderSkeleton(),
                      SliderSkeleton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: eventsUpcomingListData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return eventController.text.isEmpty || eventsUpcomingListData[index]['name']
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(eventController.text) ? EventListCard(eventsListData: eventsUpcomingListData[index]) : Text("No data");
                    }

                    ),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you debug the itemBuilder function, what are values of the variables?

Comment: @最白目 i want only that when my data not match after search then i want to show a Message "No Data"

Comment: Can you add the method where you obtain the data to the question? Right now you are passing all the items to the builder, but filtering depending on item content, that won't work properly. I.e. you pass the whole list to `itemCount`, letting the method _know_ that there are 20 items that need to be rendered. But then try to filter and end up rendering only a subset.